# Process each row and copy it to new table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I have an MSSQL 2008 table with a few million records. I need to iterate over each row, modify some of the data, and copy the updated record to a new table using a C# application that gets executed on a daily basis.

I have tried doing this using ADO.NET entities, but there are memory issues involved with this method, not to mention it is very slow. I have read up on bulk-copy libraries and SQL-only ways for copying one table to another, but none of them involve modifying records before copying them. I need to find a better way for performing this operation.

Comment: Doing things row by row is usually very slow. What sort of changes do you need to do to each row? Also, what RDBMS are you using? SQL-Server? If so, which version?

Comment: The records in the original table contain rich text. I need to convert them all to plain text and copy the plain text records to a new table.

Comment: @Ked: Is your plan to download each record to the application, convert it, and then upload it to the new table?

Comment: @ajax81: Yes, that is initially how I was doing things. This is probably a bad method though, so I am open to other ideas.

Comment: Would it be practical to modify the existing application to process blocks of records?  You might find that handling records 1000 at a time provides adequate performance without too much effort.  You can bump the number up or down to adjust the tradeoff between SQL transactions and memory requirements.

Comment: @user: I have tried performing the operation in smaller batches. The performance gains from this were negligible; it cut 15 minutes off of a job that already takes 5+ hours to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention memory issues I'm guessing you're trying to load the million rows into memory, process them and then write them back to the database.
You can avoid this by 'streaming' the data instead of loading it entirely. The `SqlDataReader` will handle buffering for you so on the reading side you can do a simple `WHILE` loop that fetches rows one by one. The actual conversion you already have working it seems so all you need to do is take care of writing the results back into the database. IMHO the fastest way to do so is by storing a buffer of multiple results (start with 100, work up and see where the sweet spot is) in a data-table and then push that data-table into the database using the `SqlBulkCopy` class. 
Rinse & repeat.

PS: Sounds like a 'fun' problem. Do you have any sample data sitting somewhere to test this out ? 5 hours sounds like a LONG time for something that looks trivial at first, then again 20 million times virtually nothing still adds up. More specifically I wonder how 'large' the data is on the RTF side : are the values ca 2k on average or rather 200k? And what kind of hardware do you run this on ?

Comment: There's multiple fields in each record that need to get scrubbed. Combine that with ORM performance and give it low CPU priority and it ends up taking a long time.

Comment: @Kededro And where exacty is an ORM in this answer that will hurt performance? I have used this approach succesfully in the past although my buffer was 5000+, not 100

Comment: @Pleun: I wasn't referring to his answer, I was responding to his questioning the execution time that I state elsewhere in another comment.

Comment: I ultimately went with this option because it was the simplest for me to implement in a short time, seeing as I have almost zero SQL experience.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest performing option would be to re-write your C# application logic into a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) so that all processing takes place on the server.

Comment: I think a function is a better approach.

Comment: True.  Although it is a minefield of requirements and performance "gotcha's" for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 1):

Checking around the internet, it looks like [Microsoft's official answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx) to converting rich to plain text is to load the data into a RichTextBox control and then pull it out with the RichTextBox.Text property.  That sucks for a lot of reasons, but mostly because it means you're going to have to get your hands dirty.  Your best bet is to write a small app that invokes the RichTextBox control and passes all of your data to/from the database (using the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) should alleviate the memory issues you mentioned).

Just as a matter of process - I would suggest building an intermediary table that your "cleansed" data rows get dumped into before appending them to your production table.  Once you get the stored proc figured out just right, you can create a trigger that automatically invokes your stored proc every time a record gets added to your dirty table.  This will ultimately eliminate the need to run your program every day to move records, as the trigger will make sure it happens "on the fly".

**Edit - one last thought**

It occurred to me that you might not be comfortable writing stored procedures and triggers, which is ok.  A more "programmatic" solution would be to kick all of the files in your dirty table out to a delimited text file, which can easily be downloaded and parsed.  Once you have the text file, you could manipulate it with your app (read it, cleanse it, create a cleansed file..what have you) and then upload for reading back into your database.  Depending on your comfort/background/skill level, this might actually be the better solution to get the job done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already have the RichText-to-PlainText operation taken care of, but I will definitely look into using a trigger rather than running over the entire table on a daily basis.

Comment: You are going to find that "Invoking the RichTextBox control" from a SQLCLR routine is somewhere between incredibly difficult and impossible, tending towards the later.

Comment: @RBarry - thanks for catching that. Updated.  (I confused myself while reading MS clrsp page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: No problem.  Many, many people have gotten way to far into a SQLCLR effort only to find this out (or something very much like it).  The restrictions on SQLCLR are extensive and not at all easy to understand ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx). Schedule a daily job that does your transformation and runs the SSIS package. This will take care of batching and memory consumption, and will offer a few [fast connectors for the read and write of data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239.aspx). You can embed your custom C# code (the RTF stripping into pure text) as an SSIS component, see [Developing Custom Objects for Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403361%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: This seems like a great option, but I do not get a say in whether we use SSIS on our servers.